# Cannot open source files

Tags: c++, opencv

I am attempting to understand the openCV library and  when i tried using identifiers from the files:

#include <opencv\highgui>

#include <opencv\cv>

it says cannot open source files. I am using visual studio and i am new to this IDE

Comment: It would be useful to post a small example and the exact error message that you see and what steps lead to that error. That would help reduce a lot of back and forth on the question.

Comment: Is your openCV library in a file?

Comment: Your question confuses me because I do not know what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Your first include probably should be `#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>` from the documentation here: [https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html)

Comment: Consider also using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use / instead of .

```
#include <opencv/highgui>
#include <opencv/cv>
```

Comment: On Visual Studio Community / Pro or Enterprise or the microsoft compiler  \ or / will work.